# What is 'dmd' in macOS activity monitor?

Tags: process

I have noticed A `dmd` process running in activity monitor.  On further inspection I have found it located in `/usr/libexec/dmd`. `launchd` is listed as the parent process. Is this a normal Mac process or is it executing on behalf of 3rd party software?